# How to remove NaN on my calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I have some problem from my calculation

```
<select name="ifin" id="ifin" class="form-control input-lg" required >
    <option selected disabled >Select Finishing</option>
    <option value="hpl">HPL</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat Duco</option>    
</select>

 <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Panjang" min="1" id="ipanjang" name="pan" >
 <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Tinggi" min="1" id="itinggi" name="ting">
```

the result would be NaN if I did not fill the `ipanjang` and `itinggi`

```
var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
var panjang = parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var tinggi = parseFloat (document.getElementById("itinggi").value);
var ht = 2.0;
var hf = 0.0;
var total = 0.0;

if (e == "hpl") {
    hf = 0.0;
}
else if (e == "cat") {
    hf = 0.5;
}
else {
    hf = 0.0;
}
total = panjang * tinggi * ht + hf;
```

Can I remove it or giving a hint that they should fill the input?

I can not use the required attribute because I do not use the submit button.

Comment: `parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value) || 0` - etc - or `parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value || 0)`

Comment: sorry ill edit it @guest271314

Answer (score 2):

```
var panjang = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ipanjang").value) || 0;
var tinggi = parseFloat(document.getElementById("itinggi").value) || 0;
```

`parseFloat` don't always return a number, it can return `number`, `Infinity` or `NaN`. ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat))

`||` operator in JavaScript:

- `var a = b || c;` equals to: `var a = b ? b : c`
- `var a = (b || c)`, `a` will be `true` or `false`

Comment: Please add an explanation for why this works and how it helps with the OP's question.

Comment: I have added it. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't `Infinity` a number? Anyway, your second dot point is wrong (unless `b` and `c` held boolean values). Adding parentheses doesn't change the behaviour of the `||` operator.

Comment: They don't need to be boolean values - but you're right about parentheses not changing the behaviour. The two dot points are equal to the first example.